# Finding the volume of a parallel piped

Tags: vectors

Given the points $P(-2,3,1), Q(2,-2,0), R(4,1,0)$.

Find the parallelepiped with edge $OP,OQ,OR$ where $O$ is the origin $(0,0,0)$.

Volume for a parallelepiped is $V=A \times B \cdot C$

So would the volume be

$OP \cdot (OQ \times OR)$

$<-2,3,1> \cdot (<2,-2,0> \times <4,1,0>)$

$<2,3,1> \cdot <0,0,10>$

area parallelepiped is $10$ but would this be correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've done it correctly.

The volume of a parallelepiped with three vectors from one vertex $\vec{P},\vec{Q},\vec{R}$ is the triple product $V = \vec{P} \cdot (\vec{Q} \times \vec{R})$:

$$V = (-2\hat{x} + 3 \hat{y} + \hat{z}) \cdot ((2\hat{x}  - 2\hat{y}) \times (4\hat{x} + \hat{y}))$$

$$V = (-2\hat{x} + 3 \hat{y} + \hat{z}) \cdot 10 \hat{z} = 10.$$

Answer (score 1):

Looks perfect! Alternately, the volume can be found as (the absolute value of) the determinant of the matrix, $$\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 3 & 1\\2 & -2 & 0\\4 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$ which is fairly simple to find via [cofactor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofactor_expansion) down the third column.

(The determinant approach has the added benefit of being generalizable to $n$-dimensional parallelpipeds for $n\ne 3.$)